# return addition and subtraction together in one function using classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am learning Python. Recently, I came across a coding exercise which I am struggling to solve. The problem is:-
Use Point object to handle vector operations addition and subtraction. For two points, it should have addition operation as (x1,y1)+(x2,y2) = (x1 + x2, y1+y2)  and for subtraction, (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) = (x1 - x2, y1-y2)  . It is required to implement a method with Point object that allows Point objects to be added together using + operator and - operator for subtraction. we need to execute add_sub in which we pass a_s_results. I am using Jupyter Notebook to run this program
Here is the code I have tried but am getting errors and I don't understand how to make this program work. I made some changes based upon whatever information I could get and understand from Google, Stackoverflow, and some other sites but I am stuck.
We can only make changes in the a_s_results function.
The below code may have some silly mistakes so apologies for that. Please guide
Thanks in advance for your help.
Here is the code:

```
class Point (object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%s, %s)' %(self.x, self.y)
        #return "Point({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)
    def __add__(self,other):
        return [self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y]
    def __sub__(self,other):
        return [self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y]    
print(dir(int))


from functools import reduce
def a_s_results(self,other):
 points = [(Point(*point) for point in points)]
 return coord([str(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, points)), 
           str(reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, points))])
#return (self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y), (self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
points = Point(1,2) + Point(3,4)
vc__add_sub(a_s_results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some problems with class interactions. Here is an example which gives addition and subtraction of points. Mainly, as the `a_s_results` is not in the class, it must not have any `self` attributes.

```py
class Point (object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%s, %s)' %(self.x, self.y)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return [self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y]
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return [self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y]    


def a_s_results(point1, point2):
    addition = point1.__add__(point2) # > [5, 3]
    subtraction = point1.__sub__(point2) # > [-3, 1]

point1 = Point(1, 2)
point2 = Point(4, 1)
a_s_results(point1, point2)
```

More specifically, when you create a `Point` object using the `Point` class (`some_point_object = Point(x_value, y_value)`, the `Point` object now has the methods `__add__`, `__sub__`, and `__repr__`, which you can call simply `some_point_object.__add__(some_other_point_object)`.

Comment: Thank you @Aarni Joensuu. That was a great help